# How parameters pass in decorator of python?

Tags: python, closures, decorator

```
def require(role):
    def wrapper(fn):
         def new_fn(*args, **kwargs):
             if not role in kwargs.get('roles', []):
                 print("%s not in %s" % (role, kwargs.get('roles', [])))
                 raise Exception("Unauthorized")
             return fn(*args, **kwargs)
         return new_fn
    return wrapper

@require('admin')
def get_users(**kwargs):
    return ('Alice', 'Bob')
```

Above code parameterizes the decorator `require` with `admin`.  It seems to that function `get_users` passes to the parameter `fn` of `wrapper`.  However, how the `get_users` passes to the parameter `fn`?

Comment: You mean you want to give `get_users()` access to the `role` value as well?

Answer (score 1):

Here `get_users()` does not pass the the parameter `fn`

since the function `get_users()` is bound to the decorator `require`

so the decorator is being called first, while your object/reference of `get_users()` is passed as an argument

for details refer https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Answer (score 1):

When a function is defined inside another function, as happens here (in fact, there are two levels of this here), the inner function(s) get access to all the outer function's variables. So it's not necessary to explicitly pass `role` or `fn` to the inner functions.

Here's what's happening:

1. `require()` is called with `role` set to `"admin"`.
2. The `require()` function defines another function, `wrapper()`, which it returns. (As an aside, this function is not well named: it is the one that does the wrapping, not the one that actually serves as the wrapper. It should probably be called `wrap()` or `decorate()`.)
3. `wrapper()` is passed the function `get_users()`.
4. `wrapper()` creates a new function, `new_fn()`, to be called *in place of* `get_users()`, and returns `new_fn()`. (Again, this is not the greatest name, it should probably be called `wrapper()` since it's the wrapper for the function being decorated.)

Now, because of the aforementioned situation where inner functions have access to all the outer functions' variables (called a "closure"), `new_fn()` has access to both `fn`, which is the function it wrapped (`get_users()`) and also the `role` parameter that was originally passed to `require()`. So it can check the user's role to see if the user is allowed to call that function, and then, if permitted, call the function and return the result, thereby serving as a substitute for `get_users()` with added functionality wrapped around the original function.

Comment: I know it's not necessary to explicitly pass role or fn to the inner functions. I am confused about that there is no explicitly meaning of fn which pass to inner function.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking.